# Python implementation for the CYK Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, nlp, automata-theory

EDIT: error is this line  `if len(rhs) == 2 and rhs[0] in T[i][k] and rhs[1] in T[k + 1][j]:`

I was able to implement the cky algorithm based off of the cky parser wiki with a small set of rules, terminals, and non terminals. But I scaled it to have more rules, words, grammar, and now it is giving me
`IndexError: list index out of range` 
Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong with a bigger grammar set?

Here is the previous smaller scale of grammar that works if that helps.

```
non_terminals = ["NP", "Nom", "Det", "AP",  
                  "Adv", "A"] 
terminals = ["book", "orange", "man",  
             "tall", "heavy",  
             "very", "muscular"] 
  
# Rules of the grammar 
R = { 
     "NP": [["Det", "Nom"]], 
     "Nom": [["AP", "Nom"], ["book"],  
             ["orange"], ["man"]], 
     "AP": [["Adv", "A"], ["heavy"],  
            ["orange"], ["tall"]], 
     "Det": [["a"]], 
     "Adv": [["very"], ["extremely"]], 
     "A": [["heavy"], ["orange"], ["tall"],  
           ["muscular"]] 
    }
```

Here's my function

def cykParse(w):
n = len(w)

```
# Initialize the table 
T = [[set([]) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)] 

# Filling in the table 
for j in range(0, n): 

    # Iterate over the rules 
    for lhs, rule in R.items(): 
        for rhs in rule: 
              
            # If a terminal is found 
            if len(rhs) == 1 and rhs[0] == w[j]: 
                T[j][j].add(lhs) 

    for i in range(j, -1, -1):    
           
        # Iterate over the range i to j + 1    
        for k in range(i, j + 1):      

            # Iterate over the rules 
            for lhs, rule in R.items(): 
                for rhs in rule: 
                      
                    # If a terminal is found 
                    if len(rhs) == 2 and rhs[0] in T[i][k] and rhs[1] in T[k + 1][j]: 
                        T[i][j].add(lhs) 

# If word can be formed by rules  
# of given grammar 
if len(T[0][n-1]) != 0: 
    print("True") 
else: 
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (because you didn't show the actual error indicating where the error occurs) that it's in this line:

```
if len(rhs) == 2 and rhs[0] in T[i][k] and rhs[1] in T[k + 1][j]:
```

and that `k` is `n-1`. If the first two conditions are true then the third one will execute and blow up.

I suspect that there is an off-by-one error in the iteration limit for `k`. Some code comments would have been useful, or at least a reference to the pseudocode you based your implementation on.

Comment: Sorry that is where the error is, I added that to the question. I will continue to try to figure out how to change it to make that line work

Comment: @john: where did you get the algorithm from? (I.e. an actual link for "the cky parser wiki". Are you perhaps talking about Wikipedia?)

Comment: Yes, I implemented it off of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm, there were some things I did not know how to do so that is why I changed it around

Comment: @john: ok. Check your computation for the iteration limit of `k`. I think it's off by one.

Comment: I solved the problem, the k limit was the problem and i added another condition before checking to make sure it wasnt out of bounds

Comment: @JohnBaltimore where did you modify? Could you please write it?